Software for computing polytopes
As can be inferred from the title, I want to do some computation on the facets representation of the polytopes given the vertices. My advisor recommended me Polymake, which is indeed useful even with thousands of vertices or more, but I noticed that it only exploits single core of my CPU. Thus, I tried to find more software that enable parallel computation.
One example is PANDA, as I tried to run the software, it indeed exploit all cores. Ironically, all cores have full utility, while the computation is far slower than Polymake. Since the paper on PANDA claims that it is faster than Polymake in most cases, because it uses a different algorithm, what could be the reason for this? One possibility is that the structure of my polytope is weird that the software is not good at solving it. Could it be also possible be the problem of the C++ version? I am definitely using a newer C++: while it is compatible, could it be slower than older versions?
Aside from this question on PANDA, I wonder if the community has any other suggestions for software. I noticed PORTA, which was designed by the same group as PANDA, but it does not seem to enable parallel computing, would it be worth a try?
The question is cross-posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4926714/software-for-computing-polytopes
Thank you all in advance!

Too soon to cross-post, according to site norms. Please note in future that it is best to wait a decent interval (a week is a good rule of thumb) before seeking answers at the other site (math.SE/MO) to where it was originally posted.

I never posted on mathoverflow/mathexchange, so thank you for pointing this out! I will follow this conventions from now on.

Does the paper on PANDA offer examples where it is faster than Polymake? If so, have you tried to check those examples?

Yes, it offers some examples where it is faster. Only one of them is offered as an example. I run this example, which turned out to be faster than Polymake.

Does the PANDA paper offer any quantitative estimates of improvement over Polymake? If so, improvement in what terms and under what conditions?

The paper does not seem to give any theoretical bound, but gives the fact that practical experiments yield very promising results. One clear improvement is that the software exploits symmetry of polytopes, and it is theoretically proven. However, I am very sure that my polytope does not have any trivial symmetry that takes advantage of this improvement.

I think you have now answered your question: No symmetry in you case.

You may like to check Normaliz software.
